# Use input from textfield P5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In my sketch I want to type a City in a textfield and insert this Information into my API-URL:

```
var Stadt='Berlin';

function setup() {
   createCanvas(500,500);
   textfield = createInput ();
   textfield.changed(newText);
   loadJSON('https://api.openrouteservice.org/geocode/search?'+
       'api_key=5b3ce3597851110001cf6248a7e197414b934680bff4449c39f000cc'+
       '&text='+Stadt+'', gotData);
}

function newText (){
   console.log (textfield.value());
}

function gotData(data) {
   var city = data.features; 
   var lon = city[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
   var lat = city[0].geometry.coordinates[1];  
   fill(0)
   noStroke();
   ellipse (lat+100, lon+100, 10, 10);

}
```

I can use `textfield.value()` to load the information into my sketch, but how can i now change `var Stadt` to the `textfieldvalue()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking to do this?

```
function newText (){
   Stadt = textfield.value();
}
```

After you make this change, you probably want to call the `loadJSON()` function again.

Comment: Yes, I tried this before but it wouldn't work - of course. You are totally right I needed to move the JSON. Thanks

Comment: Another Question:
right now i need to click into the textfield to write. Is there a way to automatically select the textfiled? To edit the HTML file would be an option I guess

Comment: @foliran Sounds like you're looking for **focus**. Please post follow-up questions in their own posts- though, so they're easier to answer.